# undefined index in $cookie['test'] in Magento 2 checkout observer

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, event-observer

The shipping method custom module's
observer shows error

**checkoutobservershipping.php**

```
 if ($_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal']) 
        {
            $id = $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'];
            $collection = $this->_storeCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $id);
        }
```

> undefined index : pickupStoreVal  /checkoutobserver.php on line 54

I have two shipping methods

> 1)Free shipping
>
> 2)Store pickup - custom module

When I select free shipping it will be showing error

I also  tried

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal']))
```

How I can resolve this?

Comment: please add full code

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'] ?? false;
if ($id) 
{
    $collection = $this->_storeCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $id);
}
```

Comment: if  $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal']  has value  what happen

it would won't affect the code

Comment: if it will have value, it will execute the code inside condition, if not, it wont. ?? is just like isset as per php 7+.

Comment: hooo   superb............

Comment: this not working bro

Comment: what error it is showing ?

Comment: no  msg is showing but show  error pop up only

Comment: If the condition is not fulfilling then definitely your code might not return something, that may be the case .. try to print something in else condition ...

Comment: hm kk                                 ..................

Answer (score 0):

You should try using **`!isset`** function, check below sample:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'])) {
    $id = $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'];
    $collection = $this->_storeCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $id);
} else {
    //your cookie is not set message
}
```