# when i select custom shiping method my other shipping methods not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, cookie, event-observer

i have two shipping methods

> 1)Custom shipping
>   2)Free shipping

when i select custom shipping it works fine

when i choose free shipping

*showing error on checkout*

> undefined index : pickupStoreVal     /checkoutobserver.php on line 70

***checkoutobservershipping.php***

```
namespace Mageants\StorePickup\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveStorePickupToOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;
    /**
     * Store Collection
     *
     * @var \Mageants\StoreLocator\Model\ManageStore
     */
    protected $_storeCollection;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Mageants\StoreLocator\Model\ManageStore $storeCollection
        )
    {
        $this->_storeCollection = $storeCollection;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->countryInformation = $countryInformation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $order->setPickupDate($quote->getPickupDate());
        $order->setPickupStore($quote->getPickupStore());
        $collection = '';
        $store = '';





       /*  $id = $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'] ?? false;
        if ($id) 
        {
        $collection = $this->_storeCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $id);
        }*/





        if ($_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal']) 
        {
            $id = $_COOKIE['pickupStoreVal'];
            $collection = $this->_storeCollection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $id);
        }


          foreach ($collection->getData() as $stores) 
        {
            $store = $stores;
        }
        if ($order->getShippingMethod() == "storepickup_storepickup") 
        {
            $storeName = explode(' ', $store['sname']);
            $streetAddress = array($store['address']);
            $firstName = '';
            $lastName = '';

            if (count($storeName) == 1) 
            {
                $firstName = "Store";
                $lastName = $storeName[0];
            }
            elseif (count($storeName) > 2) 
            {
                $firstName = $storeName[0];
                for ($i=1; $i < count($storeName); $i++) 
                { 
                    $lastName = $lastName." ".$storeName[$i];
                }
            }
            else{
                $firstName = $storeName[0];
                $lastName = $storeName[1];
            }

            $order->getShippingAddress()->setFirstname($firstName);
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setLastname($lastName);
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setStreet($streetAddress);
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setCity($store['city']);
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setPostcode(trim($store['postcode']));
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setRegion(trim($store['region']));
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId(strtoupper(trim($store['country'])));
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setTelephone(trim($store['phone']));
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setCompany('');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

how i can solve this???

Comment: have you tried this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268480/undefined-index-in-cookietest-in-magento-2-checkout-observer?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: i tried this not working